# Send XML to another server via POST

Tags: php, javascript, xml, post

I'm dealing with an incredibly bad API that requires me to send this XML:

```
<?xml_version string(335) ""1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetTicketAction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CompanyName>*name*</CompanyName>
    <IntegrationLoginId>*id*</IntegrationLoginId>
    <IntegrationPassword>*password*</IntegrationPassword>
    <SrServiceRecid>*recordId*</SrServiceRecid>
</GetTicketAction>
```

via POST (as `actionString`) to a server that is not under my control.  I've tried it with JavaScript (couldn't, cross scripting) and with CURL (got "this needs to be encrypted error").  Encryption is not mentioned anywhere in the docs, which say that it can be done with JS in IE using "full trust."

Content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if that helps.

Is there any way to send this with either JS and/or PHP?

Comment: Sending XML in a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format message? Jeez, that *is* an incredibly bad API. `this needs to be encrypted` suggests it wants you to send it via HTTPS - have you tried that? Also can you show your PHP/curl code?

Comment: Does something that requests that even count as an API?

Comment: Yeah.  Normally I can wrap my mind around poor documentation, but this seems to have been written by Cthulhu himself.

Comment: @Lusitanian Depends on your interpretation of the acronym. If you think it means Awful Programming Idiocy then yes, I'd say it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many painful years of this API slowly driving me insane, I discovered that it did NOT want me to send the XML through the standard CURL pattern of

```
$data = array(
    "actionString" => $xml
);
```

Rather, I was to do:

```
$data = 'actionString=<?xml_version string(335) ""1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GetTicketAction xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <CompanyName>*name*</CompanyName>
    <IntegrationLoginId>*id*</IntegrationLoginId>
    <IntegrationPassword>*password*</IntegrationPassword>
    <SrServiceRecid>*recordId*</SrServiceRecid>
</GetTicketAction>'
```

Future API writers: Let this be a warning.  I'm really hoping a crazed psychopath knows where this guy sleeps.